# Flutter markdown package dependency did not install correctly for me

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dart, markdown, flutter

I wan to use [flutter markdown](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_markdown)
package, but I can't.
I added dependency (in pubspec.yaml):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_markdown: "^0.0.9"
```

After I upgraded package and dependency, but when I used

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
```

statement I got error message URI doesn't exist.
I upgraded flutter and tried again, but nothing. I tried adding another way:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_markdown:
    git: "https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown.git"
```

But result is the same.

How can I solve this problem?

(I use other packages without problem.)

Comment: Have you tried restarting Intellij?

Comment: Adding a dependency on flutter_markdown: "^0.0.9" as you've shown worked fine for me. Can you show a screenshot of the error message you're encountering?

Comment: Yes I tried restarting.

Comment: http://kephost.com/images/2017/06/02/dep_problem.png

Comment: I had a similar experience yesterday with another package. After completely removing the ~/.pub-cache folder, restarting IntelliJ, and running `flutter package get` again it worked.

Comment: Do you see the Dart package in the list of *External Libraries - Dart Packages* inside IntelliJ? And can you see the package folder inside your `.pub-cache` folder, e.g. *~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_markdown-0.0.9/*?

Comment: Removing `~/.pub-cache` is a bit radical. I'd try that last and also try running `pub cache repair` first.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get` on the command line, after you added the dependency to your pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this thanks to @raju-bitter comment.
Steps:

- Close your IDE (Android Studio/Intellij Idea/etc)
- Remove the *cache*
  directory (My was located at *C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Pub*)
- Reopen your IDE.

If you still get an error then execute `flutter package get` in your terminal or from IDE menu.